# Issues with writing to Firebase database with updateChildValues with completion block

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write some entries to a Firebase Realtime database **updateChildValues (...)**. Things are working just fine unless I add completion block to the command.

Anyone having faced similar issues?

This code works just fine:

```
  private func createCalendarEntry(userId: String){
 
 var dbCalendarEntry = [String: Any]()
 let ref = Database.database().reference().child("calendar").child(userId)
  
dbCalendarEntry["name"] = event.name
      
  ref.updateChildValues(dbCalendarEntry)
}
```

Adding the completion block, nothing happens:

```
   private func createCalendarEntry(userId: String), completion: ((Error?,String?) -> ())?) {      
  ref.updateChildValues(dbCalendarEntry, withCompletionBlock:  { (error, reference) in
  if error != nil {
                print("Error updating data:")
                completion?(error, ref.key)
            }
            else
            {
                print("No Error")
                completion?(nil,nil)
            }

        })
}
```

Comment: What is the thing that you so-call 'Firebase'?  Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: Yes, exactly the Firebase Realtime database.

Comment: What is the problem when you add a completion listener? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected it would still write to the database.